# send json to Laravel using postman and android

Tags: java, php, android, json, laravel

i am trying to send json using postman to Lavavel but i facing this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MD3G.png)
this is my json code:

```
{
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "password":"testtest"
}
```

and this is Laravel codes :

```
Route::get('/r','test@store');
```

and

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Log;
class test extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        Log::info('test');
        Log::info($email);
        Log::info($password);

        DB::table('login')->insert([
            ['email' =>  $email],
            ['password' =>  $password]
        ]);
    }
}
```

also i trying using android for send data using volley and so checked Laravel logs :

```
Column 'email' cannot be null (this is Laravel logs)
```

and on android Logs:

E/Volley: [299] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://192.168.1.4:8000/r
D/error: com.android.volley.ServerErro

my android code is :

```
public class ApiService {


    private final Context context;

    public ApiService(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

            public void loginUser(String email, String password, final OnLoginResponse onLoginResponse){
                JSONObject requestJsonObject=new JSONObject();
                try {
                    requestJsonObject.put("email",email);
                    requestJsonObject.put("password",password);


                    JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://192.168.1.4:8000/r",requestJsonObject , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.d("response",response.toString());
                        }

                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d("error",error.toString());
                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                            HashMap headers = new HashMap();
                            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                            return headers;
                        }
                    };
                    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(18000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                    Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(request);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "loginUser: "+e.toString());
                }
            }

    public interface OnLoginResponse{
        void onResponse(boolean success);
    }
}
```

Comment: your laravel ROUTE method should be POST for sending data. i see you are using GET method for POSTMAN

Comment: i change ROUTE to post but get error 419 unknown status (on postman) , and on android get E/Volley: [306] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 405 for http://192.168.1.4:8000/r
D/error: com.android.volley.ClientError

Comment: @mohammadmghi If there is a 419 error, it is possible that you don't have csrf tokens for your post request.

Comment: Is this route `Route::get('/r','test@store');` defined in api.php or web.php ?

Comment: @ViperTecPro in web.php

Comment: @vivek_23 csrf-token and X-XSRF-TOKEN 
added to header but again get 419.

Comment: Can you please make a test by putting in api.php and get result by http://domanin_name/api/r ? and please put you're code in try catch block and return json data ....i'm sure you'll find a way to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wen you want to send data, you will want to use POST or PUT method on your postman, specially if you are sending a body, that means that you are sending data. Get method is used to retrieve data from a service.
Take a look into [CRUD functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) for more information.
Your postman should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sybly.png)

Last in your android code try to change this line

```
JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://192.168.1.4:8000/r",requestJsonObject , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

to use `Request.Method.POST`

Comment: i changed to POST but ger error : E/Volley: [306] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 405 for http://192.168.1.4:8000/r
D/error: com.android.volley.ClientError (in android)

Comment: sorry when changed GET to POST i this get error : E/Volley: [278] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 419 for http://192.168.1.4:8000/r
D/error: com.android.volley.ClientError

Comment: This mean that the server is found and responding, but I think that the issue is related to the Header Content-Type that define what data are you sending. Validate in postman that you are using application/json. If you don't know how to change the header in postman, read the section Headers here [link](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests/)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps people trying to search on how to send JSON data to laravel not only specific to android applications but to all. The goal of this solution is to identify whether you can send a JSON data to laravel or not.

First of all you have to download postman from https://www.getpostman.com/ to test if your API is really working or not.

Create a post request using postman. Be sure that you follow the example data below
[image]

Be sure that you set your Routes that would associate to the controller[image]

This is the controller part that will show the JSON data you sent if it was successfully accepted or not.
[image]

And also, if ever you are trying to send POST data to laravel, by default they provided a CSRF Token which is applicable for the forms if you are going to use the MVC of laravel. For the meantime, we are going to take this down and comment it out. Just go to app/http/kernel.php
[image]

and now you'll get the following result from the code earlier

```
$json = json_decode($request['json']);
echo $json->{'email'};
echo "\n";
echo $json->{'password'};
```

[image]
We tested that we were able to send data to laravel. I hope this truly helps.

Comment: Important to note, the JSON needs to be written valid - no spaces between fields, use doublequotes and wrap quotes around both key & value -- that's what worked for me, when the JSON was sloppy there were issues.